# freeMode not working in mobile browser using Swiper

Tags: javascript, swipe-gesture, swiper.js

I'm trying to use [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/) in a mobile hybrid app and I noticed the **freeMode** option wasn't responding which I wanted it do. I couldn't figure out what I did wrong until I tried [one of the demos on idangero.us](http:///swiper/demos/05-slides-per-view.html) that uses freeMode and I ran it on my desktop browser (FireFox, latest) in mobile view and it didn't work. 
I tried it on my phone as well and it didn't work there either which to me suggests that this feature isn't supported on mobile browsers.

This is kind of a deal-breaker for me and I need to know if there is any kind of known workaround? I tried [Swipeshow](https://github.com/rstacruz/swipeshow#readme) as an alternative and they make it work, but it's a jQuery plugin and I want to avoid using jQuery since I'm not using it in the rest of the app.

**Edit**

To clarify, I want **freeMode** to be false, I want freeMode to be set to false but in the demo linked above freeMode kicks in on mobile devices, it only sticks on desktop devices.

**Edit 2**

I've found that if I change to mobile mode in firefox (ctrl+shift+m) and then back again it works. What seems to happen when I do that is that something is triggered and the swipe-slides (the slider content) get their width set explicitly. After that it seems to work. Setting the width manually in my developer tools doesn't seem to be doing very much though.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured out the problem. It was a bit tricky.
At the time of initiating Swiper the div containing my swiping stuff was not showing (display: none). The solution was to wait with the Swiper initialization until I'd actually shown the div containing my swipe stuff.

The thing that really bugs me though is that Swiper didn't fail in any way, it just tried to do its best and gave me semi-functionality. I would've preferred a crash stating something like "Could not compute slide-sizes" or something like that. Instead it fails silently :(